# Smack API throws item-not-found(404) exception

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

Here is the code

```
Iterator i = MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(connectionManager.getXMPPConnection(), "test123@dulanjaya-pc");
while(i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

Comment: Found the problem; the code doesn't contain a `main(String[])` method.  Also, `connectionManager` is never initialized, and none of it is contained within a class.

Comment: ok well. connectionManager has been initialized. Not mentioned in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out.
Need to put the service as /Smack

```
Iterator i = MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(connectionManager.getXMPPConnection(), "test123@dulanjaya-pc/Smack");
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code of getJoinedRooms showed as following tells us that this method's second parameter needs a fully qualified xmpp ID. The ID example it shows is not complete, a full ID should include the resource name, such as /smack, /spark and /android.

```
 /**
     * Returns an Iterator on the rooms where the requested user has joined. The Iterator will
     * contain Strings where each String represents a room (e.g. room@muc.jabber.org).
     *
     * @param connection the connection to use to perform the service discovery.
     * @param user the user to check. A fully qualified xmpp ID, e.g. jdoe@example.com.
     * @return an Iterator on the rooms where the requested user has joined.
     */
    public static Iterator<String> getJoinedRooms(Connection connection, String user) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Send the disco packet to the user
            DiscoverItems result =
                ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection).discoverItems(user, discoNode);
            // Collect the entityID for each returned item
            for (Iterator<DiscoverItems.Item> items=result.getItems(); items.hasNext();) {
                answer.add(items.next().getEntityID());
            }
            return answer.iterator();
        }
        catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Return an iterator on an empty collection
            return new ArrayList<String>().iterator();
        }
    }
```